# How to change laravel output color on the command line?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am looking for a way to change the output color from laravels CLI tools. The output is really hard to read on a black terminal. I have tried grepping for the color yellow but i fear it might be a hex color. On the other hand it might be a composer setting any help is much appreciated.

Example Output:
[image]

Grep:

[image]
Extra Info:
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Laravel: 4.1

Comment: The colors for "this->assertResponseOk" are from PHPUnit - so you need to look in its configuration files.

Comment: It's not just phpunit, it's all errors from laravels cli tools. eg eloquent, migrations, tinker and artisan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case its not a Laravel thing - its a Ubuntu setting.

Try this:

1. Open the terminal
2. Go to edit-> profile preferences
3. Under the color tab, either check or uncheck the "use system colors" option (the opposite of what it is now). Alternatively you can also select another color scheme.